# Can I emulate usb smart card reader

Tags: linux, emulation, card-reader

I have a smart **card reader and a smart card** to access my company's private network.

Since the remote login only works on Windows/Citrix but I like to have a Linux computer, I successfully run Citrix on Win10 which runs on Virtualbox which runs on my Linux laptop.

Is there a way to **emulate the device and the card** for virtualbox so that I'm not required to carry with me the reader/card when I travel with my linux laptop?

Comment: The entire point of the smart card is that it is physical proof of identity. If you take away the unique nature of that key then it is no better than a password that you wrote on a post-it note or in a plain text file on your computer. The key being a physical and un-copyable item makes your account secure because even if someone gets your password they cannot log into your account without the physical key as well. Your company *wants* that security because if you re-use passwords and your account password gets leaked then unless you tell them that you lost the key then they are still secure.

Comment: While a smart card cannot be cloned, there is nothing preventing the party responsible for programming the smart card, from creating multiple cards with the same certificate. To be clear that’s a horrible idea. Your end goal defeats the entire purpose of the smart card, so there absolutely, is no way to create a virtual copy of your smart card. Even if there was a way, as an Administrator, if I found anyone bypassing security in this way would be fired immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

The whole point of smart cards is that they cannot be cloned, either to another smart card or an emulator.

It's not simply a read-only storage device - it's a tiny computer which can cryptographically prove its identity, and thus that you're in possession of the card. You're not able to extract the cryptographic secrets of the card, so you can't clone it.

Comment: Just to add a little to this, the algorithms and methods used to generate whatever "authentication" data that the smart card passes back may well be well known and able to be recreated, but it is the secret data that is important and not able to be simply read from the device. The company that supplied you the device may have access to a copy of that data so that they can verify your key and OTP output, but you as a user have no access to that data and I doubt your IT people would appreciate you asking to be able to copy and create hundreds of "fake" keys that could impersonate you.